# How can I use a NPN transistors to convert from 3.3v to VCC (3.9-3.0v)

Tags: cmos, led-strip, pnp

I'm wanting to drive a NeoPixel from a CMOS device. The power for the neopixel is a 4v LiPo battery and will fall from around 3.9v to 3v before it cuts off. I have a few PN2222 NPN transistors, I'm not sure what kind of circuit I should be building out of them. The neopixel needs around 0.4us timing.

**Edit**

The CMOS device will have a step up/down regulator. It's output will be a steady 3.3v. I will be powering the neopixels from the battery directly (3.9-3v is in it's operating range). I need to ensure the signal the CMOS device is sending to the neopixels matches the neopixel's input voltage.

Thanks!

Comment: PN2222 is an NPN transistor. http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/PN2222-D.PDF

Comment: If your load requires a constant 3.3V from a battery that will drop to 3V and you want maximum operating life then you'll need a buck-boost SMPS that will put out 3.3V from any input between 3 and 4V. If your load can take work down to about 2.8V, or you can accept a shorter working life, then you can get away with a much smaller, simpler & cheaper low dropout voltage regulator.

Comment: Why not giving a try to a low side driver? Use npn transistor.

Comment: Whoops, I do have NPN transistors not pnp.

Comment: I have a low amperage power source for the cmos device. I'd like to power the LED's from the Lipo battery but need to ensure it's signal pin gets the same as VCC.. I'll update my question.

Comment: NeoPixels are 5V devices...any advice that you get here will not necessarily work because you're trying to operate the devices outside of their nominal voltage range.

Comment: There are many kinds of neopixels, most operate at 5v. Mine happen to work at carrying brightness as low as 2.7v according to their spec sheet.

Comment: @reconbot, so there is a spec sheet? Would you mind posting a link? Then you might get a better answer. Also, are you open to buying something other than an npn transistor? I think you need (or might need) a level shifter. MOSFET's work much better for level shifting.

Comment: I probably need a level shifter, but it's not what I have =)

Comment: There are many ways to shift levels. I am trying to understand exactly what you need in order to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't perfect, but it gives me an almost 0.3v and VCC output from a 0v and 3.3v input.

[image: NPN transistor level shifter]

Comment: @sergey-sukhotinsky is this what you were talking about?